# Cron Job Not Running

Tags: wordpress, cron, siteground

I'm running WP 5.3.2 and Civi 5.34.0. I recently installed Wordfence free version on my site, but not sure if this has anything to do with my problem (disabled the plugin and the problem still occurs). The problem is that Cron jobs were previously working great and now, well they're not. I'm running jobs manually each day until I can figure this out.

I have a Cron job set up on my host (siteground). My job is:

[http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=NAME\&pass=PASSWORD\&key=KEY](http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=NAME%5C&pass=PASSWORD%5C&key=KEY)

If I add this to my url to test I get "ERROR: Invalid username and/or password". I can login using the user details fine and the permissions between WP admin and Civi admin correlate.

Anyone have any ideas about where I'm going wrong? I'm a novice, so explaining any solutions/ideas you might have in very basic terms would be great. Thanks!

Edit: On running my jobs manually today this error appeared at the bottom of the page:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: : : in /home/customer/www/mywebsite.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php:286 Stack trace: 
#0 /home/customer/www/mywebsite.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(421): CRM_Core_JobManager_scheduledJobFatalErrorHandler(Array) 
#1 /home/customer/www/mywebsite.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(Exception)) 
#2 /home/customer/www/mywebsite.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1172): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array) 
#3 /home/customer/www/mywebsite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke('') 
#4 /home/customer/www/mywebsite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(312): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) 
#5 /home/customer/www/mywebsite.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) 
#6 /home in /home/customer/www/mywebsite.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php on line 286
```

Comment: Siteground UK are ditching cPanel for 'Site Tools' which included changing file structures which has caused CiviCRM to fail with resources not found (there's another question on here re. this).  Is this related? Where I had several websites on one account the Civi cron jobs were assigned to the wrong website.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I don't think that's the problem. My site changed from cPanel to site tools this week. The problem occurred before the change over.

Comment: Using `wp-cli` or `cv` for cron has fewer moving parts.  Consider [switching your cron method](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#commands). Notably, these don't require a password, so you wouldn't get an error from a password check.

Comment: This might also be a lot to work out on your own as a novice; cron setup is probably the most technical part of setup! If the `wp-cli` or `cv` instructions are congusing, come chat at https://chat.civicrm.org, someone is very likely to help out.

Comment: Did you try a password without special characters. When parameters have quotes WordPress escapes them, making the password invalid.